# How do I pass a div Id as a parameter in jQuery??

Tags: jquery, function, click

I have three divs and Id like to add a click function to them.
Ideally, I'd like them all to use the same function and use ther ID as a param

When I run this, I get an alert with 'leftBox', no matter which box I click.

Can someone explain what Im doing wrong??

```
$('<div id="imageBoxOne">< src="images/carOne.jpg"></div>');
$('<div id="imageBoxTwo">< src="images/carTwo.jpg"></div>');
$('<div id="imageBoxThree">< src="images/carThree.jpg"></div>');

$("#imageBoxOne").click(moveImages);
$("#imageBoxTwo").click(moveImages);
$("#imageBoxThree").click(moveImages);

function moveImages(imageId) {
    if (imageId = imageBoxOne){
        alert('leftBox');
    }

    else if (imageId = imageBoxTwo){
        alert('middleBox');
    }
    else {
            alert('rightBox');
    }
};
```

Comment: use `==` vs `=` one is comparison, the other assignment

Answer (score 4):

In your function `imageId` refers to the event object, not the ID of the element, you should use `this` keyword. Also note that you are setting the value instead of comparing it.

```
function moveImages(imageId) {
    if (this.id === 'imageBoxOne') { 
        alert('leftBox');
    }
    // ...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
imageId = imageBoxOne
```

This **assigns** `imageId` to the non-existent `imageBoxOne` **variable**.

You want to **compare** them using `===`, and you want a **string literal** using `"..."`.

Also, `imageId` is actually the event object.  You can get the element that you added the handler to from `this`, and gets its `id` property (`this.id`)

Comment: imageId is the event object in this case, so even with the correct == or ===, it won't be equal, right?

Answer (score 1):

The argument passed by the click event is the event, which contains a lot of information. You can get the ID like this:

```
function moveImages(e) {
  var id = e.target.id;
}
```

To get the parent div's id:

```
function moveImages(e) {
   var id = $(e.target).parent().attr('id');
}
```

Comment: `e.target` most likely won't be the `div`, but rather the `img` inside.

Comment: While `e.target` is most likely the image, you can't count on that. You could try `closest` but even then it's needlessly complex.

Comment: Most often you want to refer to the bound element rather than it's child that actually got clicked. `e.target` is meant for the latter case.

Answer (score 0):

You're using "=" rather than "==" or usually better "===".

Comment: That doesn't matter, the event object will never be equal to any of the undefined variables anyway.

Comment: You're right, although his use of assignment isn't correct. Regardless, plenty of answers already pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it using `this.id` inside the function.

When you do the following. You assign the value of `imageBoxOne` to `imageId` you should use `==`.

```
imageId = imageBoxOne
```

Comment: this will fire the moveImages method immediately rather than on click.